# Data join multiple tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I'm really really a newbie to this so I hope i can explain myself with what I am having trouble with.

I have several tables that i need to extract data from into 1 table. So far I am able to extract from 2 tables but not from 3 or more.

This is what I have from extracting from 2 tables:

`select C.id , C.business, AP.firstname, AP.lastname from claims C JOIN affected_people AP ON C.ID = AP.claimid`

I have another table name named **'Messages'** which I need to extract 'comments and dateread'.

This table relates to the others via 'claimid'.

How do I extract from all three into 1 table?

Help please.

D_Klutz

I did not contemplate an issue I am having with the results obtained. Turns out that there are mutliple messages sent out per claimid but we are looking for is the very last message. How can it be coded to select only the very last message? All messages sent have a timestamp on it. Thanks for your help

Comment: add `join Message M on M.claimid = C.ID `

Comment: Check out my simple working example in [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d83ea/3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding another join on Messages should work:

```
select
   C.id ,
   C.business,
   AP.firstname,
   AP.lastname,
   M.comments,
   M.dateread 
from
   claims C 
JOIN
   affected_people AP 
      ON C.ID = AP.claimid 
join
   Messages M 
      on M.claimid = C.ID
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this suggestion, it works out great. However I did not contemplate an issue I am having with the results obtained. Turns out that there are mutliple messages sent out per claimid but we are looking for is the very last message. How can it be coded to select only the very last message? All messages sent have a timestamp on it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like this.

```
select 
   C.id ,
   C.business, 
   AP.firstname, 
   AP.lastname,
   m.comments,
   m. dateread
from 
  claims C 
  JOIN 
  affected_people AP ON C.ID = AP.claimid
  JOIN
  Messages M on C.ID=M.claimid
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
select C.ID, C.business, AP.firstname, AP.lastname, M.Message from claims AS C INNER JOIN affected_people as AP ON C.Id = AP.claimid inner join Messages as M on C.ID = M.claimid
```

Comment: Thanks, this suggestion worked only after I eddited the "M.Message" to "M.comments". Thanks...